# How to entirely disable/enable html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several elements on the page. Something like:

```
<div id="el1"><div id="el2"><span id="el3">1</span><span id="el4">2</span></div><span id="el5">3</span></div>
```

I need to disable/enable any of them, using their ids.

```
<input type="radio" name="do" onclick="disable(document.getElementById('el4'));">        
<input type="radio" name="do" onclick="enable(document.getElementById('el4'));">
```

What should be in disable() and enable() functions to really disable elements?

By "disable" I mean make it invisible for user, inaccessible by "id" and be restorable by "enable()" function.

Is it possible to turn elements on/off? Entirely, I mean.

Comment: **inaccessible by "id"** would mean that your `enable` code would be invalid.

Comment: @Shmiddty: not necessarily. For example, disable() stores the address of element as node of parent or something like that.

Comment: How would you `getElementById` if that element is **inaccessible by "id"**?

Comment: @Shmiddty: for example, leave '<!--here was element-->' in html code and restore it by replace('<!--here was element-->',elementhtmldata), I don't know yet. =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function  addEl4(){
   var elem = document.getElementById('el2'); 
   var newElem = document.createElement('div');
   newElem.setAttribute('id', 'el4');
   newElem.innerHTML = 2;
   elem.appendChild(newElem);
};

function  disable(elem){
   var container = document.getElementById('el2'); 
   container.removeChild(elem);
};
```

If you are talking in terms of removing the element from the page completely.
Then you can use the `.removeChild()` method..
Then need to append it to the div you are talking about..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YhPkj/)**

Comment: it is something near of what I am looking for =) Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
document.getElementById('el4').style.display='none'; // hide
document.getElementById('el4').style.display=''; // show
```

You could define functions like this :

```
function hide(element){
   element.style.display='none';
}
function show(element){
   element.style.display='';
}
```

I really suggest **not** to use the *enable* and *disable* words, as they have other meanings (a disabled widget is one you can see but you can't change).

A better solution would be to define a css class

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

and change the class in js :

```
document.getElementById('el4').classname='hidden'; // hide
```

If you want to completely remove an element, you may use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) :

```
var node = document.getElementById('el4');
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

but it's almost never useful. Prefer to hide as is commonly done.

Comment: The only comment I would add is to set the display equal to "" instead of "block".  This will alleviate some issues with other elements with different display types (table cells/rows/inline elements).  The browser will just apply a default to it.